# small C spreadsheet programme skeleton problem

Tags: c

Below is the initial skeleton code to create a small spreadsheet written in C. It works just fine if less than 7 Rows are required, but does not work if 7 or more lines are required. (it creates extra columns in row 7 and then hangs. Any help getting to the bottom of the problem much appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int height, width, *p;
    char page[x][y];
    char token[] = "**   ";        /** spaces for formatting **/

    printf(" \n Enter number of rows and columns. separated by a space\t" );
    scanf("%d %d", &height, &width);

    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        printf("Row %d\t ", y);
        page[x][y] = '\0';     /** prog fails at Row 2 if this line absent **/

        for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            if (y == 0)
                printf("  Col %c   ", (65 + x));    /** spaces for formatting **/
            else {
                p = &page[x][y];
                *p = token;
                printf("%d%c = ", y, (65 + x));  /** prog fails at Row 3 is these printf statements combined **/
                printf("%s" , *p);
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `page` has to be allocated

Answer (score 3):

```
int x = 0, y = 0  ;
char page[x][y] ;
```

What do you think this does, as far as the number of elements available in `page` goes? How are you currently expecting the `height` and `width` variables to influence this?

You're currently creating a `page` with no elements (which is a constraint violation). You're lucky (well, really unlucky, because it hides the problem) that the program does anything at all.

Establish some connection from the `height` and `width` inputs to `x` and `y` before allocating `page`. Once `page` is created in this way, it cannot be resized.

Comment: thanks, changing to "char page[26][30]" sorted it out.  "Height" and "width" allow the user to select the size of the spreadsheet to suit their need for a particular calculation with minimal resource usage.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
 int main()
    {
    int x = 0, y = 0  ;
    int height , width, *p ;
    char token[] = "**   " ;        /** spaces for formatting **/

    printf(" \n Enter number of rows and columns. separated by a space\t" );
    scanf("%d %d", &height , &width);

    char page[width][height] ; // allocate width x height chars
```

in your solution you are basically doing this:

```
char page[0][0] ;
```

which allocates a 2d array of width 0 and height 0 which is not really useful.

Accessing to `page[x][y]` will then access the array out of bounds for any values of `x` and `y` which results in *undefined bahaviour* (google that).

Comment: @DaveC if you find this answer usefukl, upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: I,ve been trying to put the corrected code up here for everybody to use but I cant post an answer

Comment: _"I can't post an answer"_: what happens? Is there an error message?

Comment: no error message, indeed nothing at all, I believe I went through the same process to post my answer as to post my initial question but with the corrected code. however on clicking the "Answer Your Question" box nothing happens, no little blue circle while google does something, nothing at all

Answer (score 0):

The spreadsheet skeleton code below works perfectly thanks to wise contributions above. All should feel free to use it as a basis of any small spreadsheet problem if they so wish.  "width" is limited by line length if you wish to maintain pretty formatting. but its structure allows to enter data or formulas in each cell, perform calculations (and rename rows and columns) with either pointer arrays or structures.

## include

```
    int main()
    {
    int x = 0 , y = 0   ;
    int height , width, *p ;
    char token[] = "**   " ;        /** spaces for formatting **/


    printf(" \n Enter number of rows and columns. separated by a space\t" );
    scanf("%d %d", &height , &width);

    char page[width][height] ;

        for(y = 0 ; y < height  ; y++ )
           {
            if(y==0) printf("         ");
            else printf("Row %d\t " , y);



                   for(x= 0 ; x < width ; x++ )
                      {
                       if (y == 0)
                       printf("   Col %c   ", (65 + x));   

                       else
                            {
                            p = &page[x][y];
                            *p = token;
                             printf("%2d%c = %s" , y , (65+x) , *p);
                            }
                       }printf("\n\n");

           }

        return 0;
    }
```